# How to regenerate scaffold in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I generated a scaffold with a flat model named Brick, then I created 2 new models named concrete and mortar and added has_one relationship to Brick.

Now I want to regenerate the scaffold, but I get this error:

> Another migration is already named create_brick_items:
>   Construction/db/migrate/20121210193959_create_brick_items.rb

Comment: Then delete the migration file. The new one is going to have a different timestamp anyway.

Comment: But the migration file is the only source of my fields. So how do I avoid typing in all 14 fields in the migration for the 20th time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rails generate migration AddMortarToBrick mortar:references`  or what ever brick has one of

Comment: @Unixmonkey is right, you need to delete the previous migration first, or if you are simply altering the table you need to use the appropriate naming convention. I'd prefer the later since you can see the progression of your application when reviewing later

Comment: my new anwser should be what you are looking for, this way you don't have to redefine all you original fields

Comment: wow. generate --skip-migrations --force generated blank views with no items. Basically I need to save the commandline script to generate, sorta lame.

Answer (score 1):

To your question how to regenerate scaffold. You need to:

1. If you already run migrations you have to do rollback `rake db:rollback` or if you dint need your data you can drop database and then create new database
2. Then you can destroy generated scaffold like `rails destroy scaffold Brick`
3. Finally you can generate your new scaffold `rails generate scaffold Bricks name:string mortar:references`